# Can I change .less to a.min.css with a source map and still be able to view the .less files in Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I am using this gruntfile to change my .less file to .css files.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        less: {
            development: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'assets/less',
                    src: ['*.less'],
                    dest: 'wwwroot/content/css/',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            },
            production: {
                files: {
                    "wwwroot/content/css/script.css": ["assets/less/*.less"]
                },
                options: {
                    cleancss: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
};
```

For my development build if I have ten .less files then this will create ten .css files and then I will be able to view these in the Chrome Development Tools and easily debug.

The reason I am doing this is so that I will be able to debug and look at those ten .css
files in the Chrome development tools.

Is my reasoning correct? I heard about source maps but how could I use these in my 
development build and if I used these then would I still be able to see the source
.css file names or even better the ten .less files?

Comment: The map file is used so when you are using inspector you can see what LESS file was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR yes to all of your questions ;)

To use source maps with your Gruntfile, simply add the option like this

```
less: {
    development: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'assets/less',
            src: ['*.less'],
            dest: 'wwwroot/content/css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    },
```

See [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) page for more info on the option available. Maybe, depending on your working environment, you should add the **sourceMapRootpath** option to specify where are your files.
In the end, your .css file should have a long commented line at the end. That's the source map.

There are two bit-old-but-great introduction to source maps: [Debug LESS With Chrome Developer Tools](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/12/28/debug-less-with-chrome-developer-tools/) and [Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)